# Create a plot based on two groups with the same variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(Month = c("2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", 
"2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", 
"2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11", 
"2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05"
), `Member 1` = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), `Rating 1` = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), `Member 2` = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), `Rating 2` = c(1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

My goal is to create a plot via ggplot in R where I have "Month" on the x-axis and "Rating" on the y-axis. My data contains two columns for Ratings (called Rating 1 and Rating 2). However, they have the same scale so I can call the y-axis just Rating. But then I would like to have four lines in total in the plot. You can look at it as having "Member 1" and "Rating 1" belonging together and "Member 2" and "Rating 2". So I would like to have four lines in the plot:

- One line for Member 1 and Yes
- One line for Member 1 and No
- One line for Member 2 and Yes
- One line for Member 2 and No

There should be a legend with two subgroups and each containing a title (Rating 1 and Rating 2 for the title respectively):

Rating 1:

- Yes
- No

Rating 2:

- Yes
- No

I am new to ggplot and would really appreciate any help.

What I have tried so far:

1. I created two different data frames, one for Member 1 and its Rating and one for Member 2 and its Rating. Then I changed the column names so they are identical in both data frames.

```
Data1 <- subset(Data, select=c(Month, `Member 1`, `Rating 1`))
Data2 <- subset(Data, select=c(Month, `Member 1`, `Rating 1`))

colnames(Data1) <- c("Month", "Member", "Rating")
colnames(Data2) <- c("Month", "Member", "Rating")
```

2. I used ggplot the following way:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = Data1, aes(x = Month, y = Rating, group=`Member`, fill=`Member`, color=`Member`, linetype=`Member`), color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = Data2, aes(x = Month, y = Rating, group=`Member`, fill=`Member`, color=`Member`, linetype=`Member`), color = "blue") +
  xlab('Month') +
  ylab('Rating')
```

When I run the ggplot code, I get a plot with the desired x-axis and y-axis. However, I would like to have a legend on the right as explained above. Right now, I only have a legend for the blue colors. Additionally, it would be nice if I could use  `geom_point` for one Member which makes it more visualizable.

Comment: dear nima, could you give us what you tried so far? Stackoverflow is a place to solve coding problems, not a place where you ask the others to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said what type of plot you wanted. In any case, it would be best to pivot your data into long format to create the plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = c(".value", "PersonNum"),
               names_pattern = "^(.*) (\\d)$") %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(paste0(Month, "-01"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Rating, color = Member)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(PersonNum~.) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('orange2', 'deepskyblue4')) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Update**

If you don't want facets, you could put all the lines in one panel. I think this is a harder plot to read, and less attractive / informative than the plot with facets, but is here for completeness.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = c(".value", "PersonNum"),
               names_pattern = "^(.*) (\\d)$") %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(paste0(Month, "-01")),
         Group = paste0('Rating: ', PersonNum, ', Member: ', Member)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Rating, color = Group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the plot and your effort. I did not make it clear for which I apologize but I seek a plot with lines. I updated my answer above.

Comment: @nima in that case, we just change from `geom_col` to `geom_line` - see my update.

Comment: thank you very much for the update! How could I have them in just one plot and not divided into two? So that there is only 1 y-axis with the rating instead of two as it is right now and then there are four lines in total in the same plot.

Comment: @nima the plot becomes very ugly and difficult to read if you do that, but I can show you it if you like.

Comment: @nima see my update.